# Iterating through a directory of xml files in zorba

Tags: zorba

I have a directory called auction containing a list of xml files.
How can I create a script to iterate through each file and perform operations. I am trying to use `collection()`, but it is not working.

`for $relpath in collection("auction")
for $b in $relpath/people/person[@id = "person0"] return $b/name/text()`

Please help.

More info will be provided if required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zorba-users/8W2xOQ2j0Vw

Modified it to suit my purposes. An example is as follows:

```
import module namespace file="http://expath.org/ns/file";

for $relpath in file:list("auction", fn:true(), "*.xml")

let $abspath := fn:concat("auction/", $relpath)

for $b in doc($abspath)/people/person[@id = "person0"] return $b/name/text()
```

Firstly, the module needs to imported to be used which contains the list function, which shows all the contents.
Then the iterations can go through each file and open it as a document. However, the name of the folder needs to concatenated with the filename